# Miles accrual comparisons

Tags: loyalty-programs

I am a Brazilian living in the US, and I (mostly my wife) travel regularly to Florida from Seattle, and sometimes I also fly to Brazil. I have some frequent flier numbers from Brazilian airlines, especially TudoAzul (which can be used for United flights) and Avianca Amigo (Star Alliance, also can be used in United flights). I have also AAdvantage (and TAM Multiplus) and Delta, so I'm covered on the three aliances.

Now, I am trying to find out the best program to use to earn miles on my next flight to Brazil. It's an United flight, with codeshare in Brazil with Avianca and TAM. Its cost was $850.

Now, I have several questions regarding several issues.

1. Will I earn miles for the code share flights or only the United ones?
2. From what I see here, if I earn full miles, I will earn 4250 (5 times base fare) miles on MileagePlus. From TudoAzul rules, I will earn ~10000 miles from the United segments alone (T fare: 75% of 13830 flown miles SEA-IAH-GRU-IAD-SEA, not counting the GRU-FLN-GRU segments in Brazil). United domestic tickets will usually sell by 15k miles on Azul and 12.5k (promotional) on United. All these things make me want to earn miles on TudoAzul instead of MileagePlus. However, I am not certain about the rules. **Is there any website or app where I can simulate all these scenarios or at least read a lot of things and learn how to simulate them myself?**
3. If I don't earn miles for the codeshare segments, can I provide my Amigo/MileagePlus and Multiplus/AAdvantage respectively to Avianca Brasil and TAM upon checking in to accrue miles with them?

Comment: What you really need to do is consolidate your FF memberships into one for each alliance.  Pick the carrier that you spend the most time on in each alliance and put everything on it.  Maximize your miles for both tickets and status.  Trying to nickel & dime a few extra miles will leave you with a bunch of accounts with not enough miles, rather than one with plenty of miles.

Comment: The case here is: I will earn way more miles in TudoAzul than in MileagePlus, specially in domestic flights (but TudoAzul is not part of Star Alliance). And a few more on international flights too. Since most of my flights are in-US, or US-Brazil, and I can use TudoAzul miles to buy United tickets, it seems to pay off, but I really wanted to have the hard numbers.